# Why do i have a form url point at thesame location but not at a specific file that will insert my data into database

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-4.2

My LoginUser.blade.php

```
<h1>Login</h1>

{{-- Form start comment --}}

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'user/loginUser')) }}

        <p>         
            {{ Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address') }}
            {{ Form::email('email', null, array("placeholder" => "Enter your email")) }}
        </p>

        <p>         
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
            {{ Form::password('password', array("placeholder"=>"Enter your password")) }}
        </p>

        <p>         
            {{ Form::submit('Sign In') }}
        </p>

    {{ Form::close() }}

{{-- Form end comment --}}
```

**So my Question is why should my URL points to my current LoginUser.blade.php which contains the HTML forms?? Please am new to laravel am using laravel 5.2**

Comment: Laravel can diferentiate between GET & POST request, on a GET request it shows the form, on a POST request it stores values in DB.

Comment: it does not.. you can point it to any url you want

Comment: Thanks guys it helped